# How to empty a jlist without jlist.removeall()

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist

Am using jlist.removeall to remove all the items in jlist but its not working for me

```
 private void d_location2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
           l_storieslist.removeAll();
    }
```

It is not removing anything from my jlist an dam using netbeans

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597903/how-to-clear-a-jlist-in-java

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't specify your own `ListModel` for the `JList` component, it will use `DefaultListModel`. So, you can safely type cast for the model to `DefaultListModel` and remove all the items in `JList` like this:

```
((DefaultListModel)l_storieslist.getModel()).clear();
```

Swing components which have data have its Model object for storing data. You should get the model first, then manipulate the data through the model instance.

Comment: @OP, don't forget to accept if the answer helps.

Comment: this line throws the error: javax.swing.JList$1 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel

Answer (score 0):

Use [`l_storieslist.clear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29) instead of `removeAll()`

API says

> Removes all of the elements from this list. The list will be empty after this call returns.

Comment: am not getting l_storieslist.clear() but am getting clearselection() only in netbeans

Comment: The OP is using a JList, not List.

Comment: @user2384416 : What's the data type of the `l_storieslist`?

Comment: i dono the datatype of that but i just dragged the jlist from netbeans swing palette..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    private void d_location2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
               DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel) l_storieslist.getModel();
               listModel.removeAllElements();
        }
```

Comment: After adding validate() also not working for me..

Comment: was the downvote really necessary ?

Comment: yes probably yes, but correct answer to OP question +1