# JList get/remove components

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying to manipulate with 2 Jlists and using buttons to pass the items from one list to another, like this:

[image]

So far I have tried with this chunk of code:

```
if(jliIz.getSelectedIndex() > 0) {
        jliIzKoncno.add(jliIz.getComponent(jliIz.getSelectedIndex()));
}
//jliIz is JList is the first JList
//jliIzKoncno is JList where I want to add elements
```

But it throws a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 1 // or any other index` when I try to execute the code above.

Also, how will I delete the items from the first (`jliIz`) list after I add the item to the other list (jliIzKoncno)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use some `ListModel` eg. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) class to manipulate `JList`?

Comment: thank you, this did it. I poked a bit into the documentation and figured it out by myself

Answer (score 0):

Call [JList#setListData()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setListData%28E[]%29) again after clearing the list.

Please have a look at [How to clear a JList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597903/how-to-clear-a-jlist-in-java)